# For loop printing keys twice

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

myArray:

```
[1488559492944,29, 1488556363891,29, 1488554612089,29, 1488553812873,29, 1488555337118,29, 1488556552117,29, 1488555250090,29, 1488553465926,1]

for (var i = 0; i < keyValueArray.length - 1; i = i + 2) {
  var xValue = keyValueArray[i].toString();
  console.log("x " + xValue);
  var yValue = parseInt(keyValueArray[i+1]);
  console.log("y " + yValue);
  data.addRows([
   [xValue, yValue]
  ]);
}
```

why does this loop print this result:

```
x 1488559492944
y 29
x 29, 1488554612089
y 29
x 29, 1488555337118
y 29
x 29, 1488555250090
y 29  ?
```

What I want is just to add even numbers to a table as values and uneven ones as keys, but it adds 29s to x's..

Comment: use modulo operator to find even numbers.

Comment: Can't reproduce. Post a [mcve].

Comment: presumably because `data.addRows` has a `console.log` somewhere within it. The code you provide does not have the output you provide.

Comment: It doesn't.  It prints `x 148...44`, then `y 29`, then `x 148...91`, then `y 29`, and so on...

Comment: try to `console.log(i);`and see the results. I'm almost sure it is because i is not changing it's value.

Answer (score 0):

maybe it's the solution for you

```
for (var i = 0; i < (keyValueArray.length / 2); i++) {
  var xValue = keyValueArray[2*i].toString();
  console.log("x " + xValue);
  var yValue = parseInt(keyValueArray[2*i+1]);
  console.log("y " + yValue);
  data.addRows([
   [xValue, yValue]
  ]);
}
```

Comment: Why do you think this should work better than what he has? What's the problem with his code and not with yours?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the google dataTable API, here's what you're looking at -- which does exactly what it seems you're trying to do.

```js
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {
      // Define the chart to be drawn.
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('string', 'Element');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Percentage');
      
      var keyValueArray = [1488559492944,29, 1488556363891,29, 1488554612089,29, 1488553812873,29, 1488555337118,29, 1488556552117,29, 1488555250090,29, 1488553465926,1]

for (var i = 0; i < keyValueArray.length - 1; i = i + 2) {
  var xValue = keyValueArray[i].toString();
  var yValue = parseInt(keyValueArray[i+1]);
  console.log("x="+xValue+", y=" + yValue);
  data.addRows([
   [xValue, yValue]
  ]);
}



      // Instantiate and draw the chart.
      var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('myPieChart'));
      chart.draw(data, null);
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  <!-- Identify where the chart should be drawn. -->
  <div id="myPieChart"/>
```